# how to fetch rows from table using difference between months (say 14 months) between two dates columns using plsql

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle10g

I have a table **po010**  in which columns are polref, POLCRCDTE,PUPDTE.

I have to fetch polref from table po010 where , difference of months between POLCRCDTE and PUPDTE is ateast 14 months.

My tries are .

```
SELECT polref,POLCRCDTE,PUPDTE FROM po010,
    GROUP BY polref
    HAVING months_between(pck_utility.f_dtcnv(POLCRCDTE),pck_utility.f_dtcnv(PUPDTE))>14
```

**Note:** POLCRCDTE and PUPDTE are number formats ,
and pck_utility.f_dtcnv  returns date in DATE format taking number format as input.

Second try is

```
DECLARE 
sysdte DATE;
req_dt DATE;
BEGIN
SELECT system_dt INTO sysdte  FROM cs340;
SELECT add_months(sysdte, -14) INTO req_dt FROM po010;
dbms_output.put_line(req_dt);
select * from po010 where pupdte <= pck_utility.f_dtcnv((add_months      (sysdte ,-14)));
```

END;

**Note** : here  taking  system_dt  from cs340 because in other scenario , i have to compare the dates between those two.

Please help me out.

Both the codes are giving error.
first one error is ORA 00900
second one is giving ORA 06550 
.

Basically i need this resultset in a cursor that i need to use in a procedure.

Comment: Why are you grouping by `polref`? Are the two date fields the same for every value of `polref`? If not, which value do you want to return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HAVING` is used to filter results based on an aggregate, `months_between()` is not an aggregate function.

Perhaps you just want to use `WHERE`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT polref,POLCRCDTE,PUPDTE 
FROM po010
WHERE  months_between(pck_utility.f_dtcnv(POLCRCDTE)
                     ,pck_utility.f_dtcnv(PUPDTE)
                     )>14
```

You typically need to `GROUP BY` every non-aggregate field in your `SELECT` list, I'm not sure what you were after with your `GROUP BY` clause, so I removed it and used `DISTINCT` in the `SELECT` list.

Comment: thank you, This one is working :-)
But what about the other scenario , where i need to compare the date using system_dt from cs340 (i.e other table) and that system_dt   is actually not system date which we select from dual.
Please give it a look.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT polref,POLCRCDTE FROM po010 
WHERE months_between(pck_utility.f_dtcnv(POLCRCDTE)
                     ,pck_utility.f_dtcnv(SELECT system_dt FROM cs340)
                     )>14

This is the query i am using , getting ora 00936 : missing expression.
:-(

Comment: @prnjn I don't follow what you're after in the 2nd one, it looks like you're trying to populate a variable with a value, but why are you using `FROM cs340`, isn't that a table with multiple values?  I'm not up on syntax for variable usage in Oracle.

Comment: cs340 is a table with only one row.
and thanx for the reply , :-) 
It is done successfully , taking the example of first one.

SELECT DISTINCT p.polref,p.POLCRCDTE , c.system_dt FROM ddl00.po010 p, ddl00.cs340 c
WHERE months_between(pck_utility.f_dtcnv(POLCRCDTE)
                     ,system_dt)>=14

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your support,b it is solved now.

I can use like this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.polref,
                p.polcrcdte,
                c.system_dt
FROM   ddl00.po010 p,
       ddl00.cs340 c
WHERE  Months_between(pck_utility.F_dtcnv(polcrcdte), system_dt) >= 14
```